# Azure database randomly stopped working after publishing UWP app

Tags: c#, azure, http, uwp

Ive made an app that uses Azure easy tables and connects using the following:

```
 try
        {
            await ctv.combatDrillsTable.Initialization;
            await ctv.combatDrillsTable.InitLocalStoreAsync();
            await AddItemsAsync();
        }
        catch
        {
            var addError = new MessageDialog("Connection to your drills could not be established at this time, returning to " +
                "main menu");
            await addError.ShowAsync();
            if (MainPage.MyFrame.CanGoBack)
            {
                MainPage.MyFrame.GoBack();
            }
        }
```

This was doing a GET request fine the last few weeks but now the connection error throws, I checked my Azure portal and the drills are there, the server overview shows the following:

[HTTP Error stats](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pK98X.png)
Im not really sure whats wrong and why Azure has just decided to stop working. I get the same results on bith my local machince is Visual Studio 2017 and the app installed on windows from the store.

Answer (score 0):

> Im not really sure whats wrong and why Azure has just decided to stop working.

Firstly, you need to enable logs in Azure, in that case you could access the information logged by Azure and check the logs to find the detail reason. Details for how to do please reference [this article](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/web-sites-enable-diagnostic-log).

Since  you're using easy table, the azure backend should be `node.js`. After enabled logs, you could access logs by address like: `https://{your app name}.scm.azurewebsites.net/api/vfs/LogFiles/Application/index.html`.

If you still cannot resolve your issues by checking the log details, you could upload the log for further looking.